# django ajax runtime error - URL doesn't end in slash

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I am practicing from a tutorial where I have reached to create a search box with jquery and ajax. Every thing is going good, except, when i press any key in the search, I get an error,

> RuntimeError at /articles/search You called this URL via POST, but the
>   URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't
>   redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your
>   form to point to localhost:8000/articles/search/ (note the trailing
>   slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

I checked for "/" in my code, but its there. Don't know what's going on. Please help.

application's urls.py:

```
    url(r'^search/$', 'article.views.search_title'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def search_title(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)

    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', {'article': article})
```

I'm using jquery version:
`jquery-2.0.0.min.js`

ajax.js:

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/articles/search/',
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

And even when I inspect the ajax.js, in the last line

> $('#search-results').html(data);

It reads it as:

> $('#search-results').html(date);

My main url:

> (r'^articles/', include('article.urls')),

Comment: Could you post your main `urls.py`? Have you tried restarting the server after changing the code?

Comment: Sure. I have edited. And yes, i have tried restarting the server too.

Comment: Could your client web browser have cached some JS files with wrong content ?

Comment: Sorry, i had a typo in my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I had a typo. In my views.py:

```
def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)

    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', **{'article': article})**
```

It should have been:

```
    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', **{'articles':articles})**
```